# Advancing PRNGs in NumPy and general distributions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I would like to use the [random number generation of NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html) to draw numbers from different distributions. For a given generator, seed and distribution, I would like to be able to draw the `i`'th number in the sequence, without having to draw all `i - 1` numbers before it. The three [bit generators](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/index.html) `PCG64`, `PCG64DXSM` and `Philox` all have an [`advance()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/generated/numpy.random.PCG64DXSM.advance.html#numpy.random.PCG64DXSM.advance) method, which seems to promise the functionality I am after.

For e.g. the `PCG64DXSM`, I would do

```py
seed = 42
bit_generator = np.random.PCG64DXSM(seed)
generator = np.random.Generator(bit_generator)
# Draw n uniform numbers between 0 and 1
n = 20
nums = [generator.uniform(0, 1) for _ in range(n)]

# Only draw the last number
bit_generator = np.random.PCG64DXSM(seed)
generator = np.random.Generator(bit_generator)
bit_generator.advance(n - 1)
num = generator.uniform(0, 1)
assert num == nums[-1]
```

This works great for the uniform distribution, though not for other distributions in general. In particular, I am also interested in the normal and Rayleigh distributions.

To show how the `advance()` method fails for these distributions, I have written the test code below:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot(ax, rand, n=20):
    BitGenerator = [np.random.PCG64DXSM, np.random.PCG64, np.random.Philox][0]
    seed = 42
    bit_generator = BitGenerator(seed)
    generator = np.random.Generator(bit_generator)
    x = [rand(generator) for _ in range(n)]
    ax.plot(x, 'C0-')
    for i in range(n):
        bit_generator = BitGenerator(seed)
        generator = np.random.Generator(bit_generator)
        bit_generator.advance(i)
        x = rand(generator)
        ax.plot(i, x, 'C1.')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3)
plot(axes[0], lambda generator: generator.uniform(0, 1))
plot(axes[1], lambda generator: generator.normal(0, 1))
plot(axes[2], lambda generator: generator.rayleigh(1))
plt.show()
```

[image: test code]

The three panels in the produced figure correspond to the uniform, normal and Rayleigh distributions. The blue line is the random sequence drawn sequentially from a single generator, while the orange dots are individually obtained from fresh generators using `advance()`. Using `advance()` fails for the normal and Rayleigh distributions after a while. How long this takes depend on the `seed` and which bit generator is used.

##### Questions

- Why does `advance()` work perfectly well for the uniform distribution, yet not for other distributions generally?

  - Why **does** it work for the first few random numbers in each sequence?
- Is this "intentionally" / known behaviour?
- **How can I get around it?**

Answer (score 1):

Running `advance(n)` means discarding `n` outputs of the generator's underlying PRNG.  However, in general, a random variate generation algorithm can use more than one PRNG output to generate a given random variate.

All three generators in your example produce 64-bit outputs, and for all three generators, `generator.uniform()` produces each random variate by taking one PRNG output.

On the other hand, the number of PRNG outputs used by `generator.normal()` and `generator.rayleigh()` is variable, and does not always equal 1.  For example, `normal()` uses the ziggurat algorithm, which consumes one PRNG output *most of the time*, but not always.   The same is true for the exponential generator, which is ultimately used by `generator.rayleigh()`.

See the [source code of NumPy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/random/src/distributions/distributions.c) to see how each algorithm is implemented.  Also, in my article on random variate generation, see "[Fixed amount of 'randomness'](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Implementation_Considerations)".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and pointers. Is there then no way around this problem, at least so long as I stick to NumPy?

Comment: one (slightly less efficient) way of getting around this is to use the CDF of distribution from scipy instead.  i.e. generate uniform floats in [0,1] (which always uses a single draw from the underlying bit generator) and transform to distribution of choice

Comment: One way to proceed is to take one PRNG output from the original bit generator, use it as part of the seed for another bit generator, and generate a random variate with the latter generator.

Comment: @SamMason Nice! So for e.g. Rayleigh, I can swap out `np.random.Generator(np.random.PCG64DXSM(42)).rayleigh(size=1000)` for `scipy.stats.rayleigh().ppf(np.random.Generator(np.random.PCG64DXSM(42)).uniform(0, 1, size=1000))`.

Comment: @jmd_dk yup, but I'd suggest not doing this if possible.  I'd use the other tools provided by numpy's random module to get repeatable results.  Having code depend on being able to seek to some place in the sequence suggests that something is wrong with the design

Comment: @SamMason It's for use with multiprocessing, with each process being designated a piece of a bigger probem. Globally, I want to draw the same numbers regardless of how many processes I use. Without seeking, each process has to draw all the numbers and not just its own.